# Spring Resttemplate parses Object as String

Tags: java, json, spring, resttemplate

I have the following model:

```
public class MyObj implements Serializable {

        private Long id;

        private Object body;
        ..........

        public Object getBody() {
            return body;
        }

        public void setBody(Object body) {
            this.body = body;
        }

        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        ............

}
```

The body field contains a JSON object.

When I am trying to send MyObj as a request to a POST endpoint as following:

```
restTemplate().postForObject("url",myObj,String.class);
```

the following request will be sent:

```
{
                "id": 6,
                "body": "{\"Status: \":\"1\",\"Date: \":\"2017-9-12 11:3:51.328\",\"Source: \":\"xxx\", .....}",
                ......
}
```

which is not the result I want since body seems to be parsed as String while I want it to be parsed like this:

```
{
                "id": 6,
                "body": {"Status": "1", "Date": "2017-10-3 16:39:58.591", "Source": "xxx"},
                ......
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: why do you want to declare body as Object? If you know the structure just create a class

Comment: No I don't know the structure.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was the following :

```
@JsonRawValue
private Object body;
```